# Редактирование изображений

Tags: изображения

Подскажите, пожалуйста, литературу по редактированию изображений. Интересно изменение яркости, контрастности, работа с кривыми, различные фильтры, как это все реализовать программно. Понимаю, что это все обработка сигналов, но там все обобщенно, и если честно, ни хрена не понятно =) Хотелось бы что то более близкое к теме. Спасибо

Answer (score 1):

Одно время тоже заинтересовался этим - у меня знакомый сишник проявил интерес к интерфейсам и графике. Думал ему на день варенья подарить подобную книжицу...

И что думаете? Всю область излазил. Все сайты с продажами книг перевернул. НЕ НАШЕЛ! Все как вы говорите: "обобщено" и примерно.

Пришлось подарить кальян и сделать подборку ссылок по данной теме.  )))))))

Comment: это было давненько (пару лет назад), да и сейчас, смотрю, мало чего изменилось - поисковики выдают почти исключительно GIMP :)

Comment: что же это, мне придется обработку сигналов разбирать? я даже специалиста какого-никакого по этому вопросу не могу найти... хотя таких программ миллион и маленькая тележка!

Answer (score 1):

Гонсалес Р., Вудс Р. Цифровая обработка изображений - это ЦОСовые фильтры. Они улучшают изображение.

Работа с кривыми - это алгебра, проще искать статью + книги по графике ( кривые Безье и NURBS).
Яркость и контрасность можно по-разному менять. Либо на основе ЦОС, либо:

-яркость это тупо добавление чисел к РГБ.

-контрасность - вычисляешь средний уровень яркости, дальше что меньше среднего уменьшаешь, что больше увеличиваешь( проще всего построить функцию линейную, екоторая если меньше среднего уровня выдает число меньше 1 если больше среднего - увеличивает)

И да, очень много фильтров можно сделать на основе HSV модели ( сепия, перевод цветов в нужное и тд).

А вообще по этой теме не много книг и если нужны конкрентные алгоритмы лучше копать инет. Простые вещи можно найти.

Comment: ну как я, собсна, и сказал :)